# How to send data to a web Service Using Winj.xhr

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am new in `Winjs` coding I have data in a list .
and i want to send that data to my json Web Service .

I have a success to call to web service and i have the response so the web service is 
working but the data doesn't seem to be sent. I dont know how to declare the data.

I have many data to sent like(username,first_name,last_name,password) to my  `Register.json`
The `Register.json` have this response after the execution:

```
{

"format":
"json",

"success":
false,

"errors":
["User name is empty"],

"result":
null

}
```

so i m sure that data doesnt be sent

```
function Register() {
    var dataArray = [

   {
       username: "Marley",

       first_name: "dog",

       last_name: "ded",

       password: "pdre4252d"

   }];

    WinJS.xhr({

        url: "my_Base_URL/Register.json",

        type: "post",

        headers: { "Content-type": "application /x-www-form-urlencoded" },

        data: dataArray

      // data:JSON.stringify(dataArray)

    }).done(

          function complete(result) {
              if (result.status === 200) {
                  console.log("Success: Response Text: " + result.responseText);
              }
              else {
                  console.log("Fail:Response Text:  " + result.responseText);
              }
          },

          function error(error) {
              console.log("error");
             },
          function progress(result) {
            }

);
}
```

I will be thinkful if someone give me some help.

Comment: It seems like the web service is requiring a user name, but one is not being provided in the WinJS.xhr options. Does the service have any authentication requirements?

Comment: No it's opened , it's ok now with XMLHttpReuest , i used .send(data) nd it's ok but i don't know the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

The `WinJS.xhr()` is a **promise wrapper** around `XMLHttpRequest`, which means it delegates your parameters to an `XMLHttpRequest` object and returns a `WinJS.Promise` object. The parameters may not be delegated correctly so play with adding and empty string for a username and such. Otherwise you can mimic the same functionality by creating your own `WinJS.Promise` with an `XMLHttpRequest` inside.